# How to select all values by default in arcgis tool's multivalue parameter using python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-toolbox, tool-validation

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and have three parameters, Feature class, field and  a multivalue parameter respectively in ArcGIS tool. I populate multivalue parameter with unique values of  feature class on selection of feature class and field. Here is the code snippet:

```
def updateParameters(self):

    if self.params[0].value and self.params[1].value:
        fc = str(self.params[0].value)
        col = str(self.params[1].value)
        self.params[2].filter.list = sorted(
                                         set(
                                             row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [col]) if row[0]
                                            )
                                           )
```

By default, none of the value is checked in the tool.

[image: Unselected values]

How can I check all values of multivalue parameter through **ToolValidation class** using python 2.7?

[image: All selected]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the value of the parameter to the values you want to be checked, at least when using a Python Toolbox. The same should be true for your case.

For example:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    p = arcpy.Parameter()
    p.datatype = 'String'
    p.multiValue = True
    p.name = 'test'
    p.displayName = 'Test'
    p.parameterType = 'Required'
    p.direction = 'Input'
    p.filter.list = ['One','Two','Three','Four']
    return [p]

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    parameters[0].value = ['Two','Four']        
    return
```

[image]

*edit*

For your code example this would look like:

```
def updateParameters(self):
    if self.params[0].value and self.params[1].value:
        fc = str(self.params[0].value)
        col = str(self.params[1].value)
        vals = sorted(set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,[col]) if row))
        self.params[2].filter.list = vals
        self.params[2].value = vals
```

Comment: The problem here is that you don't know what strings will come forehand, so you cannot set them checked on parameter update, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov In some cases you may not, but in Surya's example, the values are being explicitly added in `updateParameters`, so of course they are known.

Comment: hm as I got it, Surya obtains the list of values in the updateParameters. Would it work just to assign the list he gets to be the values of self.params[2]?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Yes, the same list that is set as the `filter.list` should also be set to the `value`. That should result in all items being selected.

Comment: that is great. Would you update your code to include the piece of code Surya has with the cursor? You define the p.filter.list right in the getParameterInfo while he runs search cursor first in the updateParameters.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Sure. I was trying to explain how it worked rather than "paste this into your code," but I can see how it's confusing

Comment: @EvilGenius great answer but I'm curious, where in the Help does it say that sending a list to the _value_ property checks on/off checkboxes?

Comment: @Hornbydd I couldn't find anything in the docs that relates to this, but given that the value is set to a ValueTable containing the selected items when the tool is run, it made sense to set it to a list to select the values beforehand. I tested it and it works, although possibly not documented.

Comment: Hmmm... only an "Evil Genius" would have thought to have done that, your tag is justly deserved! :)